# Is "considering taking" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, progressive-aspect

I've seen the following sentence in a newspaper. Is it grammatical?

> He's considering taking early retirement.

*Taking* = present progressive was used near another present progressive?

Comment: I agree with Barrie England's answer, and I'd add that the non-finite verb form "taking" looks to me like a gerund, a verb form that functions as a noun. Specifically, it functions as the direct object of "considering"; it is also a verb form having "early retirement" as its own direct object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatical. *Considering* is part of the finite present progressive construction *is considering*. *Taking* is not a present progressive form, but a non-finite verb form.

Comment: Right. Though there is what Haj Ross calls the ["Doubl-ing constraint"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4177686) that makes sequences of two _-ing_ words in a row feel uncomfortable for native speakers.

Answer (score 4):

[thefreedictionary.com page on consider](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consider) states the following:

> You can say that someone is considering doing something in the future.
>
> - They *were considering opening* an office on the West Side of the city.
> - He *was considering taking* the bedside table downstairs.
>
> **Be Careful!**
>
> Don't say that someone 'is considering to do' something.
>
> Collins COBUILD English Usage © HarperCollins Publishers 1992, 2004, 2011, 2012

Comment: However, *considering **whether** to do something* is fine.